# Jmeter - Need to push 200 XML lines in a XML request with a changing parameter

Tags: xml, jmeter

I am all new to Jmeter,Please help me in getting the below implemented.

Scenario:
This is web services scritping in Jmeter. We have an XML request in which we have a parameter ${ItemNode}. In the subsequent line we need to pass an computed value say ${TargetXML} which pass 200 XML lines changing only the ArticleID (Rest of the XML line is static with only article Id changing ) which I need to get Uniquely from User parameter file. Similarly for next ${ItemNode} we need to pass 200 XML lines for next set of articles.

Basically we need to push 200 XML lines (Only Articles unique and rest of the XML line is static) per ${ItemNode}.

Please help me with inputs.

Answer (score 0):

For instance, you have XML file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

1. In your [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler switch to "Body Data" tab and put your XML file there

   [image: Body Data]
2. Replace the bit you need to change with [JMeter Function or Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html), the most suitable functions are:

   - [__StringFromFile()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) - if your source user parameters file has only one entry per line it's easier to use it
   - [__CSVRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) - if your user parameters file has > 1 columns

   So your final version should look like:

   [image: Parametrised XML]

See:

- [Function Helper Dialog](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#function_helper) - available from Options -> Function Helper Dialog - to assist in constructing function with proper syntax
- [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) post series - for comprehensive information on aforementioned and other useful JMeter functions.